# docker rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden

Tags: docker, nginx

I am quite sure I have run this docker-compose before but this time when building it, I get this error. note I am using windows.

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:  1.2s 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.23.1:       
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
ERROR: Service 'nginx_ser' failed to build : Build failed
```

this is my `nginx` container

```
nginx_ser:
    container_name: nginx_container
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      # nginx last service
      - chat_django_ser
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

this might be only because of nginx